# Catch invocation errors in celery

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery worker that is connected to RabbitMQ so that a client can make requests to the worker. For the requests, I use the celery functions`apply_async` and `apply` to invoke functions remotely.

I use the parameter `expire` to determine how long the task will wait to finish. I do this with the hope to deal with tasks that hang, but in my example this doesn't work. When I run this example with the worker down, the caller hangs indefinitely.

Here is an example, where the function `hello` runs remotely, and `test_hello` invoke this function:

```
def test_hello():
    hosts = ["host1", "host2", "host3"]
    for host in hosts:
        print "%s\n" % host
        output = myapp.hello.apply_async(queue=host, args=(host,), expires=70)
        print output.get()

@task(name='myapp.hello')
def hello(hostname):
    """ dummy function that returns a simple message """
    time.sleep(60)
    return "Hello %s" % hostname

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "test_hello"
    test_hello()
```

My problem is that I want to catch the error when the worker is down, or when the request hangs because the worker crashed in the  middle of the call. How can I catch these errors?